# artifactory license manager with bamboo

Tags: artifactory, bamboo

I'm having trouble finding anything definitive in the artifactory documentation.

With Bamboo, using the Artifactory plugin, I want to enable license checks (as shown in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/License+Control )

However using generic deployment, I'm not finding any option for license checks.

If anyone can give me a pointer on how to enable the license checks properly for release builds etc it would be appreciated.  Only real documentation I can find on the latest version keeps pushing x-ray which is overkill for my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The license control capability was [deprecated](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/What%27s+New%3A+Self-Hosted#What%27sNew:Self-Hosted-DeprecatedFeatures) in the Artifactory 7.0 release and was replaced, as you noted, by the Xray [license compliance](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Managing+Compliance+Licenses) which provides richer information and support for additional package types.